# want to rename 2 files with different extension in python

Tags: python

I am working in one project where i need to rename the multiple file in same folder and for that i write down the code but when i am running this code then it's throwing the error like "file already exist". is there any way where i can skip those file which is already present with sequqnce and rename the rest of file in sequence, please help me.

Example of file:

```
0.png
0.xml
```

Code which i wrote:

```
    import os
    png_files = set()
    xml_files = set()
    base_path = r'C://Users//admin//Desktop//anotate'
    for x in os.listdir(base_path):
    name, ext = x.split('.')
    if ext == 'png':
    png_files.add(name)
    elif ext == 'xml':
    xml_files.add(name)
    counter = 0
    for filename in png_files.intersection(xml_files): # For files that are common (same names)
    if filename.exists():
    print ("File exist")
    else:
os.rename(os.path.join(base_path,filename+'.png'),os.path.join(base_path,str(counter)+'.png')) 
#Rename png file
os.rename(os.path.join(base_path,filename+'.xml'),os.path.join(base_path,str(counter)+'.xml')) # 
Rename xml file
counter += 1 # Increment counter
```

Comment: I dont get it!! what are you trying to do! so u have folder annotate with files like `0.png`, `1.xml` ... and you want to rename them according to your counter ?? I mean I dont get that part. What are you exactly trying to do!

Comment: say you have files like `0.png`, `1.png` ... `10.png`. Now when you renaming say `0.png` to `10.png` in your base folder u already have `10.png` that's why it is showing file exists error while renaming

Comment: tell me what are you doing I might help with alternate approach :)

Comment: Currently your question is rather hard to understand because the code you posted isn't properly formatted. Can you reindent your code so it looks correct to you? It's also helpful to add the actual error to your question, including the traceback

Comment: you need to mention users using "@" sign or we wont get notified of your comment. so before writing comments just add "@name" in the comment !! :)

Comment: guys i want something which rename my file and skip any file which is already exist and then continue to the next file

Comment: ok so you want to name all your files as numbers like `0.png`, `1.png` ... and I assume that the files you want to rename are not numbered so they look like `sample.png`, `dog.png` ... am I right ??

Comment: yes @luckyCasualGuy, could you please hep me in this

Comment: ok i will start working then !! :)

Comment: Thanks @luckycasualguy that will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Please make sure to copy your folder as backup as this will remove your old folder and instead will place a new folder with same name this is just in case anything goes wrong.

```py
from pathlib import Path

directory = Path("./Annotate")
out_dir = Path("./Out")

out_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

pngs = list(directory.glob("*.png"))
xmls = list(directory.glob("*.xml"))

for num, file in enumerate(pngs):
    write_here = out_dir / "{}.png".format(num) 
    write_here.write_bytes(file.read_bytes())
    
for num, file in enumerate(xmls):
    write_here = out_dir / "{}.xml".format(num) 
    write_here.write_bytes(file.read_bytes())
    
for files in directory.iterdir():
    files.unlink()
    
directory.rmdir()
out_dir.rename(directory)
```

change the **base_dir** variable to path of your folder containing images and xmls.
output will be generated in the folder named **Out** in the `current working directory`.

**Example:**
say your `annotate` folder looks like this

```
/Annotate
--/0.png
--/0.xml
--/1.png
--/1.xml
--/dog.png
--/dog.xml
--/cat.png
--/cat.xml
```

After running the script The `Annotate` folder will look like.

```
/Annotate
--/0.png
--/0.xml
--/1.png
--/1.xml
--/2.png
--/2.xml
--/3.png
--/3.xml
```

**I am not exactly renaming the file but I am making a new directory with file naming format you want.**

**NOTE:**
If you annotate more images i.e you run the script again after annotating more images I would recommend that you delete the old Output folder. It should not matter though but for safety!!
`Make sure you have latest python installed.`

### As per request, here is the step by step code explanation!

you import required module

```py
from pathlib import Path
```

make two **path objects**:
1.`directory` specifying your input directory path.
2. `out_dir` specifying path to temporary output folder

```py
directory = Path("./Annotate")
out_dir = Path("./Out")
```

Makes a folder specified in the Path object, if folder exists no error is thrown the code continues.

```py
out_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
```

Makes two separate python list of all the paths inside the selected path object that ends with `.png` and `.xml`.

```py
pngs = list(directory.glob("*.png"))
xmls = list(directory.glob("*.xml"))
```

loops through the python list `pngs` and `xmls` and writes down binary data of selected file with the name specified by index of enumerate in the output path object location.

```py
for num, file in enumerate(pngs):
    write_here = out_dir / "{}.png".format(num) 
    write_here.write_bytes(file.read_bytes())

for num, file in enumerate(xmls):
    write_here = out_dir / "{}.xml".format(num) 
    write_here.write_bytes(file.read_bytes())
```

Deletes everything from the path object specified.
than remove the path object.
and rename the temporary path object to old path that was just removed.

```py
for files in directory.iterdir():
    files.unlink()

directory.rmdir()
out_dir.rename(directory)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222024/discussion-on-answer-by-luckycasualguy-want-to-rename-2-files-with-different-ext).